# Bootstrap Dropdown Nav won't change

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a **nav** with **multi-column dropdowns** from **multiple headers.**

I have managed to get "**Perennials**" looking how I want but when I copy that dropdown into "**Bulbs**" and make changes to the pasted code in the "Bulbs" section, these changes do not update.

I want to change all of the **h6** and a in the **Bulbs** section (and others in the future) but they only change when I amend the initial **"Perennials" dropdowns.**

```html
<li class="nav-link" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Perennials
  </li>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-multicol2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Award Winning</h6>
         <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Achillea</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirsium</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sweet Pea</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nerine</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Penstemon</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Award Winning</span></a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Perfect for Pollinators</h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alstroemeria</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Daphne</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Digitalis</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hellebores</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Phlox</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All For Pollinators</span></a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Climbing</h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clematis</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lonicera</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rose</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Passiflora</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wisteria</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Climbing</span></a><br>
    </div>
      <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Drought Tolerant</h6>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Acanthus</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Agapanthus</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delosperma</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Geranium</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hibiscus</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Dought Tolerant</span></a><br>
    </div>
        <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Long Flowering</h6>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Abelia</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Buddleja</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dianthus</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hydrangea</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Petunia</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Long Flowering</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Scented</h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Actaea</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erysimum</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lupin</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rhododendron</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Salvia</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Scented</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Good for Cut Flowers</h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Abeliophyllum</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delphinium</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Iris</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Osteospermum</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Primula</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All for Cut Flowers</span></a>
    </div>
      <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Shop By</h6>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Best Sellers</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Special Offers</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Plant of the Month</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Flowering This Year</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Suitable for Beginners</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Perennials</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
 <li class="nav-link" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Bulbs
  </li>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-multicol3" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Bulbs</h6>
         <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tulip</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirsium</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sweet Pea</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nerine</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Penstemon</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Award Winning</span></a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Perfect for Pollinators</h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alstroemeria</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Daphne</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Digitalis</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hellebores</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Phlox</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All For Pollinators</span></a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Climbing</h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clematis</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lonicera</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rose</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Passiflora</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wisteria</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Climbing</span></a><br>
    </div>
      <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Drought Tolerant</h6>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Acanthus</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Agapanthus</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delosperma</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Geranium</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hibiscus</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Dought Tolerant</span></a><br>
    </div>
        <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Long Flowering</h6>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Abelia</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Buddleja</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dianthus</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hydrangea</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Petunia</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Long Flowering</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Scented</h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Actaea</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erysimum</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lupin</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rhododendron</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Salvia</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Scented</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Good for Cut Flowers</h6>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Abeliophyllum</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delphinium</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Iris</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Osteospermum</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Primula</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All for Cut Flowers</span></a>
    </div>
      <div class="dropdown-col">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Shop By</h6>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Best Sellers</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Special Offers</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Plant of the Month</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Flowering This Year</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Suitable for Beginners</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Perennials</span></a>
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS

```css
.dropdown-multicol2{
  width: 50%;
}
.dropdown-multicol2>.dropdown-col{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 24%;
}
.dropdown-item {
    padding-top:1%;
    padding-bottom:1%;
    font-family:Gotham;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:0.85em;
}
.dropdown-item:hover {
    padding-top:1%;
    padding-bottom:1%;
    font-family:Gotham;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:0.85em;
    color:#7c2a82;
}
.dropdown-header {
    color:#7c2a82;
    font-size:1em;
    font-family:Old Standard TT;
     text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px grey;
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-bottom:0%;
}
.dropdown-divider {
    margin:0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and modify as you wish

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .dropdown-multicol2{
            width: 50%;
        }
        .dropdown-multicol2>.dropdown-col{
            display:inline-block;
            width: 24%;
        }
        .dropdown-item {
            padding-top:1%;
            padding-bottom:1%;
            font-family:Gotham;
            font-weight:100;
            font-size:0.85em;
        }
        .dropdown-item:hover {
            padding-top:1%;
            padding-bottom:1%;
            font-family:Gotham;
            font-weight:100;
            font-size:0.85em;
            color:#7c2a82;
        }
        .dropdown-header {
            color:#7c2a82;
            font-size:1em;
            font-family:Old Standard TT;
            text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px grey;
            margin-top:1%;
            margin-bottom:0%;
        }
        .dropdown-divider {
            margin:0%;
        }
        .dropdown-menu.dropdown-multicol2.show {
            width: 675px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu.dropdown-multicol3.show {
            width: 720px;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    </style>
    <title>tugrulyildirim.com.tr</title>
</head>
<body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownMenuButton" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Perennials
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-multicol2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Award Winning</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Achillea</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirsium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sweet Pea</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nerine</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Penstemon</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Award Winning</span></a><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Perfect for Pollinators</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alstroemeria</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Daphne</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Digitalis</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hellebores</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Phlox</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All For Pollinators</span></a><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Climbing</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clematis</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lonicera</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rose</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Passiflora</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wisteria</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Climbing</span></a><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Drought Tolerant</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Acanthus</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Agapanthus</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delosperma</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Geranium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hibiscus</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Dought Tolerant</span></a><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Long Flowering</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Abelia</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Buddleja</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dianthus</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hydrangea</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Petunia</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Long Flowering</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Scented</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Actaea</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erysimum</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lupin</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rhododendron</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Salvia</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Scented</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Good for Cut Flowers</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Abeliophyllum</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delphinium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Iris</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Osteospermum</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Primula</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All for Cut Flowers</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Shop By</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Best Sellers</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Special Offers</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Plant of the Month</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Flowering This Year</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Suitable for Beginners</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Perennials</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownMenuButton2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Bulbs
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-multicol3" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Bulbs</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tulip</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cirsium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sweet Pea</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nerine</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Penstemon</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Award Winning</span></a><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Perfect for Pollinators</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Alstroemeria</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Daphne</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Digitalis</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hellebores</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Phlox</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All For Pollinators</span></a><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Climbing</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clematis</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lonicera</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rose</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Passiflora</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wisteria</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Climbing</span></a><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Drought Tolerant</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Acanthus</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Agapanthus</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delosperma</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Geranium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hibiscus</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Dought Tolerant</span></a><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Long Flowering</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Abelia</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Buddleja</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dianthus</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hydrangea</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Petunia</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Long Flowering</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Scented</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Actaea</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erysimum</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lupin</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rhododendron</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Salvia</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Scented</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Good for Cut Flowers</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Abeliophyllum</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delphinium</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Iris</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Osteospermum</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Primula</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All for Cut Flowers</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-col">
                            <h6 class="dropdown-header" style="margin-left:0%;padding-left:5%;">Shop By</h6>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Best Sellers</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Special Offers</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Plant of the Month</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Flowering This Year</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Suitable for Beginners</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span style="color:#7c2a82;">View All Perennials</span></a>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
</body>
</html>
```